# one website on shared server won't process .php, but will process .php3

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2

I'm working on a SugarCRM website that, when visited, will upload index.php to your computer instead of displaying it. After working on it for a little while, I tested a test.php file on different websites on the server. test.php worked on other websites, but not the SugarCRM website. So I changed the extension to test.php3, and it worked. I'm wondering if anybody could tell me why this is happening, and how I could fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your tags I assume that we're talking about Apache 2 here. What you could try to do is to put the following in your .htaccess file:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
```

But it won't work unless Apache allows such overrides in .htaccess files.

The further course of action is hard to tell without knowing the level of your access to the server. If you can configure the server's Apache, you might as well add these handlers straight into the httpd.conf and be done with it.

Comment: thats right. except now it's not executing the code, its just displaying the last line of code onscreen. any ideas for that?

Comment: Would be great to see the actual code - at least the last few lines of it, including one that is being "displayed".